# What is the syntax for an if-let statement?

Tags: syntax, rust

I encountered this snippet in some example code.  It works fine, but I got a linter error saying that it should be structured as an if-let statement.

```
match event {
  glutin::Event::WindowEvent { event, .. } => match event {
      glutin::WindowEvent::Closed => return glutin::ControlFlow::Break,
      glutin::WindowEvent::Resized(w, h) => gl_window.resize(w, h),
      _ => (),
  },
  _ => ()
}
```

This was my attempt to restructure it:

```
if let _ = glutin::Event::WindowEvent { event, .. } {
    match event {
       glutin::WindowEvent::Closed => return glutin::ControlFlow::Break,
       glutin::WindowEvent::Resized(w, h) => gl_window.resize(w, h),
       _ => (),
   }
}
```

Oops, that's a syntax error.  What would be the correct way to clear the linter warning?

After looking at the code more closely, I realized that I don't understand the syntax.  `glutin::Event::WindowEvent { event, .. }` looks like the syntax for creating a new instance of `WindowEvent` but how can that be allowed inside a match statement?

Also, what does the `..` mean?  I'm familiar with `..Default::default()`, but not the double dot by itself.

Comment: It's the other way around: `if let glutin::Event::WindowEvent { event, .. } = event { ... }`

Comment: Thanks @E_net4!  An answer explaining the syntax would be much appreciated.

Comment: [**One** question per post, please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829).

Comment: I stand corrected @Shepmaster

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax that eludes you is called [destructuring](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/first-edition/patterns.html#destructuring).

This pattern allows to match certain fields in a struct, enum, or tuple. You therefore cannot just use if let with the destructuring on the right side of the binding.

The code you want is probably:

```
if let glutin::Event::WindowEvent { event, .. } = event {
  match event {
      glutin::WindowEvent::Closed => return glutin::ControlFlow::Break,
      glutin::WindowEvent::Resized(w, h) => gl_window.resize(w, h),
      _ => (),
  }
}
```

There is a possible confusion between the right hand `event` variable and the one extracted from the pattern.
The use of `event` in the destructuring is made mandatory because it needs to use struct fields by name.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!  I tried searching for `rust lang .. syntax` but it didn't turn up much.

Comment: There shouldn't be a comma after the `match` expression.

Answer (score 3):

Directly quoting from [The Book, second edition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch06-03-if-let.html):

> The `if let` syntax lets you combine `if` and `let` into a less verbose way to handle values that match one pattern and ignore the rest.

It also provides this example:

```
if let Some(3) = some_u8_value {
    println!("three");
}
```

The correct syntax is `if let «pattern» = «expression» { ... }`, and not the opposite written in the question.

```
if let glutin::Event::WindowEvent { event, .. } = event {
    // ...
}
```