# How do I retrieve the error value on a Result without an empty match arm?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I have a function that returns a `Result`. If I want to panic if there's an error, I know I can use `match`:

```
fn foo() -> Result<(), u32> {
    Err(1234)
}

fn another() {
    match foo() {
        Err(n) => panic!("The error value is {}", n),
        Ok(_) => {} // an unsettling empty block...
    }
}
```

I found the `is_err` function, which can be used like this:

```
fn another() {
    if foo().is_err() {
        panic!("The error value is x"); // how to get the "1234" here?
    }
}
```

It seems that there's no way to get the error value. How to retrieve the `1234` value in the example above?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Why does Rust need the `if let` syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27534364/155423); [What is the syntax for an if-let statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46981148/155423); [What is the idiomatic way of using an if-let binding when matching a `Result` and still being able to capture the error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47248583/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: The [duplicate applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d65b0499e30e1a0aad756089311e1b72)

Comment: @Shepmaster It's the `if let` syntax, you're right, thanks.

Comment: @Shepmaster - Honestly I'm new to SO, but this being marked duplicate seems to me a bad trend. All of the referenced duplicates are explicitly asking about if-let syntax. If the OP doesn't _know_ about if-let, how does not answering the question (by answering in comments) help anything? How is this even a duplicate at all? Is this trend codified in SO reference documentation somewhere?

Comment: @chub500 being marked as a duplicate doesn't require that the questions be identical, but that they are *answered* by the answers of the duplicate target(s). That's why the box at the top says "This question already has answers here". The question in the current form will stay around forever and serve as a redirect (an automatic one if you aren't logged in to SO), so anyone with the same phrasing as the OP will still find a match in a search engine.

Comment: I see - thank you for the clarification. Being marked 'duplicate' is not necessarily a slap on the wrist then.

Comment: @chub500 absolutely not. Many duplicates are immensely useful. Of course, there are some low-effort duplicates. Those types of questions often also get a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use the if-let syntax (mentioned in the comment by @shepmaster)?

```
fn foo() -> Result<(), u32> {
    Err(1234)
}

fn process_error(res: u32) {
    println!("Logging err: {}", res);
}

fn another() {
    if let Err(e) = foo() {
        process_error(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't answer duplicate questions.

Comment: Should I delete it?

Comment: There's no rule that you must, but *I* would. I value having fewer sources of answers so that it's easier to maintain them.